# Запуск приложения при старте системы

Tags: настройки, ubuntu

Как сделать так, чтобы определенное приложение стартовало при старте системы? Я знаю как запустить приложение при входе пользователя (через .bashrc). А вот как сделать так, чтоб оно стартовало для всех пользователй, причем при включении ПК?

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос довольно объемный, поэтому опишу лишь в общих чертах.

1. Создаем скрипт для запуска|останова приложения в папке `/etc/init.d/` (за основу можно взять `/etc/init.d/skeleton`)
2. Делаем его исполняемым

`sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/local`

1. `sudo update-rc.d <имя_скрипта> start 40 2 3 4 5 . stop 30 0 1 6` (здесь задается порядок старта и останова. В данном случае скрипт будет выполнять последним при загрузке и останавливаться первым при выключении)
2. Для удаления скрипта из автозагрузки нужно выполнить

`sudo update-rc.d -f <имя_скрипта> remove`

**P.S.** Для понимания вышеописанного необходимо прочитать страницы руководства по update-rc.d (`man update-rc.d`). А также ознакомиться с уровнями загрузки (см. папки /etc/rc0.d, /etc/rc5.d и т.п.). Про уровни загрузки можно почитать [здесь](http://linuxopen.ru/2008/01/15/khitrosti-zapuska-sluzhb-v-linux..html).